# How is self assigned in inheritance?

Tags: objective-c

Using the iOS SDK, I have a subclass of UITableViewController

```
@interface MyViewController : UITablewViewController

@end
```

The dataSource and delegate properties of the UITableViewController get set to MyViewController automatically.

I am just not sure why this happens. I thought 'self' would be the UITableViewController instance when it gets initialized, and not the subclass.

Can someone help explain how the delegate and dataSource point to the subclass, not the UITableViewController.

Thanks

Comment: Please give us some code so we can see what you do for ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall try to put it in very simple words:

1. You are creating an object of your UITableViewController subclass and not of the UITableViewController itself.
2. Your delegate and dataSource will point to the viewController which is putting the table view on screen (that's usually done).
3. So now all the delegate and dataSource methods will be called from this viewController.

Look into [this sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318) from Apple. Hopefully this should make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this-

1.Inherit MyViewController from UIViewController
2.Make a object of UITableViewController in MyViewController
3. set delegate and datasource properties to self.

Code :
*MyViewController.h*

```
    @interface MyViewController : UIViewController

    @end
```

*MyViewController.m*

```
    @implementation MyViewController
      -(void)viewDidLoad{
        UITableViewController *tableView = [[UITableViewController alloc]init];
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.datasource = self;
      }

      ---------- 
   @end
```

I think it will help you ...